# Hide Alert Me in Sharepoint Ribbon

Tags: 2013, alert

I have customized alerts message in alerts.template for front end users.

I don't want users to select "Alert Me" and get OOTB emails from SharePoint. How do I hide "Alert Me" from the ribbon?

Comment: check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/630fc0c6-945a-4362-880b-2a098abdf433/how-to-remove-alert-me-option-from-the-sharepoint-2013-community-list-context-menu?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: But this will affect only 1 library or list . Need a generic solution . Cant we take care using permissions ?

Comment: so you want to do this across farm?

Comment: Yes i think thats a valid option .

Comment: check this one, he is talking about to change the file in hive folder...yiou can go to 14/15 hive https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c83159a3-1e10-4a37-aa0b-541658162f0f/how-to-hideremove-alert-me-action-menu-item-from-custom-listdocument-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: you can always hide it through CSS, so that it will only affect list/libraries under your site....

Answer (score 0):

Create an elements.xml and use the below lines to hide on all forms/ribbon

```
   <CustomAction
Id="RemoveAlertMeButtonFromLibrary"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RegistrationId="101"
RegistrationType="List">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Actions.Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Alert" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WebPartPage.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Share.AlertMe" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Alert" />
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

FYI ,http://the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Hiding-Multiple-Ribbon-Buttons